# Cognos Report Studio Text box prompt not function proporly

Tags: textbox, cognos, cognos-10

I use conditional block to show different text box prompt when user choose different filter in my first prompt page. Now, I set the text box with same setting(no required, multi-select:yes, multi-line:yes, other are no) and similar filter script in my queries. However, when I run the report, I can't get the same output. My first text box miss right half of text space. How can I fix it? Thanks!
Click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jrtk8h4oqHelBUcE96dkVMQWs/view?usp=sharing) for the first screen shot.
Click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jrtk8h4oqHN2ZfaGthai14alE/view?usp=sharing) for the second screen shot.

Comment: Those links don't work (permissions).

Comment: OK! I updated the link! Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample report spec would be helpful but based on the screen shot, one of two things is happening:

1. The first prompt does not actually have the multi-select option set.

OR

2. The filter item in the actual query that the first prompt is populating is not multi-select friendly.

An example of #2 would be if you tried to set enable multi-select values but then the filter it is populating into is set to something like:

```
[table].[field] = ?firstPrompt?
```

Instead of:

```
[table].[field] in (?firstPrompt?)
```

If this isn't the case, definitely edit in a simple sample report specification so we can see more of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks!! It solved my problem. It's kind of weird that it didn't happen on my other reports. And is "contain" multi-select friendly? If not, what can I change. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Contains is likely not multi-select friendly since you're checking whether a single value exists in another value.  For multiple values I think you generally want to use the IN clause.